# Django Models: Aggregate over not directly related models

Tags: django, django-models

I have following models:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
some_field = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class UserRating(models.Model):
subject_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='rated_user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
rating_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='rating_user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
rating = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("subject_user", "rating_user")
```

I am trying to get a queryset of all UserProfiles with annotated average value of rating in UserRating model.

I've tried doing the following:

```
    queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
    for profile in queryset:
        user = profile.user
        ratingset = UserRating.objects.filter(subject_user = user).values_list('rating')
        if len(ratingset) == 0:
            profile.rating = 0
        else:
        profile.rating = sum(ratingset) / float(len(ratingset))
```

However this throws the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'
```

I thought about calculating the sum by iterating over ratingset, but my approach seems like an overkill. Is there any simpler way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django actually offers various methods for aggregating directly via SQL which is far more efficient. This should get the job done:

```
profiles_with_ratings = UserProfile.objects.annotate(rating=Avg('user__rated_user__rating'))
```

docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/

Side note: what you actually have is a many to many relationship between users that you're building manually for some reason.